# Problems in JSON decoding in Swift (XCode6 beta2)

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, swift, swift-playground

I made a small demo to request and decode data using a restful API,
the API URL is:

```
http://interface.bilibili.tv/playurl?cid=1168445&otype=json
```

This is an API of video URLs, I wrote and ran the code below in playgrounds:

```
import UIKit

var url = NSURL(string: "http://api.bilibili.tv/view?type=json&id=822920&batch=1&appkey=0a99fa1d87fdd38c")

var data = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(url, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingUncached, error: nil)

var json : AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil)
```

And then in Xcode, it exits automatically every time. But if I change the URL to:

```
http://freegeoip.net/json/8.8.8.8
```

The code runs without problems.

[image]

I will appreciate if anyone can help me, is this a bug of **Xcode 6 beta** or is there something wrong with my written code?

[image: Xcode fatal]

Comment: Welcome to early betas. Thought this is really more like an alpha in terms of stability.

Comment: try to step away from playground, it is very unstable environment currently. anyway, your code works quote well on my computer.

Comment: @holex you mean you can run my code outside playground?!?!

Comment: @DickyTsang, yes, you can do certainly.